# Android: Scan screen for QR code every XX seconds

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode

I have created an android Application that displays the front facing camera inside a SurfaceView.

I would like employees to walk up to the device, show a QR code and enter the building.

So far I have tried converting the SurfaceView contents to a bitmap and reading the contents using the Google Barcode Codelabs to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this?

I need the app to be constantly waiting for a QR code.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to do this with a library that can be launched with startActivityForResult. Then when the callback triggers (onActivityResult) you can check if its a valid QR code and then relaunch the QR code scanning activity.

One thing I would note is that a security system this is very insecure so don't use it for a building where security is important.

You will need the zxing barcode scanner app to make this code work.

```
package com.example.userme.qr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);
    }
}
```